# What is the best way to duplicate rows based on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table below:

```
ID Start_Repeat_1 End_Repeat_1 Start_Repeat_2 End_Repeat_2
A               3            7              2            5             
B               1            4              2            5
```

My goal is to duplicate "A" 5 times and "B" 4 times with the output below

```
ID Repeat_1 Repeat_2
A         3        2
A         4        3
A         5        4
A         6        5
A         7     NULL       
B         1        2
B         2        3
B         3        4
B         4        5
```

The logic is that "A" needs to be duplicated with numbers between 3 and 7 in one column and numbers between 2 and 5 in another column so it needs to be duplicated at least 5 times.

The version below would also do. The order between the two columns does not matter.

```
ID Repeat_1 Repeat_2
A         3        2
A         7        5
A         6        3
A         5     NULL
A         4        4
```

Can someone help me with this using SQL Server 2018?

The dataset size is about 10,000 rows and each row is duplicated at most 10 times with a total of 10 columns like this

```
ID Repeat_1 Repeat_2 Repeat_3 Repeat_4 Repeat_10
A         3        2        1        1         1
B         7        5        1        1         1
```

Comment: `using SQL Server 2018?` No such version. Do a `PRINT @@VERSION` to obtain the correct `SQL Server` version

Comment: Can you explain what is the last data sample in your question ? How is it relate to the others ?

Comment: i think there is no single query fulfill this. you can create a tmp table, then run a iteration by applying pivot/while. and insert the records to the tmp table based on the requirement

Comment: My best try is to use a "while loop" and "insert into" to 10 times to duplicate the first column. I would then need to repeat this 10 times to the next 10 columns before joining the 10 sub-tables into 1 table with 10 columns. This is basically 100 duplicates per ID so I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: Sorry, the version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: please show your best attempt query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of a tally table. In the following solution, I have use a recursive cte to generate one.

Alternatively you can use a recursive cte to generate one on the fly

---

```
-- Tally Table

create table tally
(
    n int
)

-- generate 1000 numbers for tally table
with cte as
(
    select n = 0
    union all
    select n = n + 1
    from   cte
    where  n < 1000
)
insert into tally (n)
select n
from cte
```

---

The `cross apply` is to find the maximum difference between the repeat_1 or 2 etc.

```
-- The query

select t.ID, 
       Repeat_1 = case when n.n <= (End_Repeat_1 - Start_Repeat_1) 
                       then t.Start_Repeat_1 + n.n 
                       end,
       Repeat_2 = case when n.n <= (End_Repeat_2 - Start_Repeat_2) 
                       then t.Start_Repeat_2 + n.n 
                       end,
       Repeat_3 = case when n.n <= (End_Repeat_3 - Start_Repeat_3) 
                       then t.Start_Repeat_3 + n.n 
                       end
from  tbl t
      cross apply
      (
           select m = max(d)
           from   (
                  values
                  (End_Repeat_1 - Start_Repeat_1 + 1),
                  (End_Repeat_2 - Start_Repeat_2 + 1),
                  (End_Repeat_3 - Start_Repeat_3 + 1)
                  ) n (d)
      ) m
      inner join tally n on  n.n >= 0
                         and n.n < m.m
```

[dbfiddel demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65e0fcb2c1bafe1c3f9ee2343c9f540c)

Answer (score 2):

you can use recursive cte :

```
with cte as (
select * from test
union all 
select Id
    , case when Start_Repeat_1 + 1 > End_Repeat_1 then null else Start_Repeat_1 + 1 end 
   ,End_Repeat_1 
   ,case when Start_Repeat_2+ 1 > End_Repeat_2 then null else Start_Repeat_2+ 1 end
   ,End_Repeat_2 
from cte 
where Start_Repeat_1 <= End_Repeat_1 and Start_Repeat_2 <= End_Repeat_2 
) 
select ID,Start_Repeat_1,Start_Repeat_2
from cte 
where coalesce(Start_Repeat_1,Start_Repeat_2) is not null 
order by ID
```

> ```
> ID | Start_Repeat_1 | Start_Repeat_2
> :- | -------------: | -------------:
> A  |              3 |              2
> A  |              4 |              3
> A  |              5 |              4
> A  |              6 |              5
> A  |              7 |           null
> B  |              1 |              2
> B  |              2 |              3
> B  |              3 |              4
> B  |              4 |              5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=33f085cf6a0904e192d70f6ec048dad5)*